# ActionEvent getWhen

Tags: java, events

How can I convert the long `timestamp` returned from `getWhen` into a readable date and time?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
System.out.println(new Date(event.getWhen()));
```

For other representations you can try the `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`Date(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) constructor